# can see allure result in jenkins with codeceptjs

Tags: jenkins, allure, codeceptjs

I am trying to see allure results on Jenkins.
I am using from my jenkins

```
 codeceptjs run --plugins allure
```

then on codeceptjs folder, the output generated.
I downloaded allure 2.7 and try to set it.

my path is  Results :

```
 target/allure-results
```

when I run the build I am getting

> allure-results does not exists

any my allure test is 0...

what can be done?

Answer (score 1):

the issue is resolved.
This is allure bug.
Need to give path without spaces and spacial cricketers .